# Why does this break in jQuery 1.7.x?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code snipplet shows what my issue is:

```
var $div = $('<div>');

$('span').live('click', function() { this.innerHTML = 'changed'; });

$div.append(
    $('<span>span</span>').click()
);

$div.appendTo('body');
​
```

This works as expected in jQuery [**1.6.x**](http://jsfiddle.net/BSbAA/) but not in [**1.7.x**](http://jsfiddle.net/NQ9jk/)

Why is it not working in 1.7.x? Is it a bug? Is there any way to get it to work in 1.7.x?

EDIT: [`.on` doesn't change anything!!](http://jsfiddle.net/3BTaz/)

Comment: It is working fine for me.... What is the problem?

Comment: When I test this, the span is changed to 'changed' on pageload on JQ 1.6.x but on 1.7.x it waits for the click. Looking at your code, isn't that the behaviour you want?

Comment: @alykhalid: no, i want to invoke the click function before its appended. They should both be set to "chaned" before its appended

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way that event handling works has changed in the 1.7 release.  Before the `<span>` is added to the DOM, events triggered on it will not bubble up to the `<body>` as they once did (erroneously, in my opinion; the 1.7 behavior makes much more sense).

The triggering of the event on the `<span>` probably works, but because the event does not bubble to the `<body>` the actual handler that deals with your `.live()` setup cannot be called.

*edit* — it may be the document element to which events bubble; whatever, the point is the same.

*edit again* — Here's a way to make this work so that you can trigger handlers before adding your elements to the DOM:

```
$('<div></div>').on('click', 'span', function() {
    this.innerHTML = "Changed!";
}).append($('<span>span</span>'))
  .find('span').click().end()
  .appendTo($('body'));
```

That sets up the "click" handler as a delegated handler *on the nascent `<div>` directly*. Then, after appending the new `<span>` to that element, it's *then* possible to trigger a "click" on that `<span>` and have the handler be called.  That happens before the whole thing is appended to the `<body>`.

Comment: Is there any way for me to accomplish what I'm trying then without having to append it first to the body and without having to bind an event handler to each element?

Comment: Pointy is right, the old behavior was a bug and only existed for about one version. The element should be in the DOM so that the event can correctly bubble. If you are doing something where events aren't expected to honor the document structure, I'd suggest a pub/sub plugin like the one in Amplify.js or Ben Alman's Tiny Pub/Sub.

Comment: @qwertymk yes, that's exactly what my updated example does. It sets up an event handler on the container element that you're building. You can then add all the elements to it that you want, but because it's not part of the real DOM yet they are not on the page. You can then trigger events and the handlers will be called, all **before** you add the outer container to the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method **is deprecated**. Use .on() to attach event handlers.

http://api.jquery.com/live/ *(as pointed out by the commenters, this still works in jQ 1.7)*

**To your edit:**

try

```
var $div = $('<div>');

var span = $('<span>span</span>');
span.click(function() {
    this.innerHTML = 'changed'; 
});

$div.append(
    span.click()
);

$div.appendTo('body');
```

​
​
http://jsfiddle.net/3BTaz/3/

Comment: I want it to be changed before its appended. The event isn't getting called even though I'm clearly calling it

Comment: Because it needs to be inside the div when you use delegate: http://jsfiddle.net/3BTaz/2/

Comment: You could use this solution http://jsfiddle.net/3BTaz/3/ but it's not very efficient when you want to add multiple spans.

Comment: @qwertymk Check my updated answer for a way to do this in 1.7.x such that the handler is called before the element is appended to the DOM. You need to establish the delegation on the new container elements, and then trigger the event after appending the target elements to that (but *before* appending to the main DOM).

Answer (score 2):

The working solution for both 1.6 and 1.7

```
var $div = $('<div>');
$('span').live('click', function() { this.innerHTML = 'changed'; });
$div.append('<span>span</span>');
$div.appendTo('body');
$('span').trigger('click');
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/NQ9jk/1/)

---

However, omit the risk of using a deprecated function with replacing `live` with `on`

```
$('span').on('click', function() { this.innerHTML = 'changed'; });
```

Comment: Yes, but this still involves triggering the handler *after* the element has been appended to the DOM.

Comment: @Pointy, The handler should be apart from the append logic, and thus trigger to follow up later too. Lets see what OP thinks

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the result of `.click()` to `.append()`. The interesting thing here is that it worked in 1.6 as nothing is returned from *your* function. This is likely due to internal changes in how `.live` works, or how `.click` invokes its listeners.

[Notice how this works in 1.7](http://jsfiddle.net/gsngN/)

```
var $div = $('<div>');

$('span').live('click', function() { this.innerHTML = 'changed'; });

$div.append(
    $('<span>span</span>')
);

$div.appendTo('body');
$('span').click();
```

Comment: The return value of `$.click()` is a jQuery object, in this case the span element. It doesn't return the callback function's return value. As you can see in the OP's demo, the span element *is* appended to the div, it's just the click event that doesn't get triggered.

Comment: I want the event handler to be called before it's appended. All your doing is appending it then triggering it